# How to make observable run in parallel and return each promise as they resolve?

Tags: rxjs

For example, I have an observable from an array of promises. Now, I want the promises to run in parallel. Then, I want the observable to start emitting values as soon as a promise resolves. Which means, the order in which the values come is NOT important.

How to do that?

Comment: Make an observable from each promise and merge the observables. http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create one Observable for each Promise and then merge all of them.

Here's one way of doing it:

```
promises = [
 fetch('http://slowwly.robertomurray.co.uk/delay/6000/url/https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'),
 fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'),    
 fetch('http://slowwly.robertomurray.co.uk/delay/3000/url/https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2')
 ]

 promises.reduce((acc, promise) => 
   rxjs.merge(acc, rxjs.from(promise)), rxjs.empty()
 ).subscribe(console.log)
```

This would differ from forkJoin, which would only return when all of them emmited:

```
rxjs.forkJoin(promises.map(promise => rxjs.from(promise))).subscribe(console.log)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `mergeMap` in this case.

For instance, if you have an array of strings representing the url of REST endpoints, you can do something like this

```
const arrayOfUrls = [
  'https://my_service/myendpoint_1',
  'https://my_service/myendpoint_2',
  'https://my_service/myendpoint_3',
];

from(arrayOfUrls) // this creates a stream strings emitting each endpoint url
.pipe(
  mergeMap(url => fetch(url))  // mergeMap creates a stream of the results of each REST call
)
.subscribe(
  next: result => console.log('result of REST call', result)
)
```